# How do I conditionally find the oldest date in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to fill column I & J with the quantity and location with the oldest expiry date and where location does not equal ship bin.

Raw Data & Summary Report

[image]
[image]

In the above Quantity should show 100 and Earlest Date 10/01/2019

The formula I've tried is:

IF(A2='Inventory Details'!A:A,IF('Inventory Details'!G:G=2,MIN('Inventory Details'!C:C)))

But I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

If your data source starts in column A, then the column G is missing.

Your formulas is also missing a few elements. You have two nested IF statements but you only populate the TRUE part after the condition.

I assume you want to combine the two conditions with AND, get the minimum date of column C where A2 = column A AND column G = 2.

This can be done with

```
=MIN(IF((A2='Inventory Details'!A2:A5)*('Inventory Details'!G2:G5=2),'Inventory Details'!C2:C5,""))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

The two conditions in the IF statement result in two arrays of TRUE or FALSE values. These two arrays are multiplied with each other and only where both arrays have a TRUE, the resulting array will have a TRUE. For these positions, the values from column C will be taken into consideration for the MIN function.

This concept may take some time to get used to.

Also, unless you like staring at the "Calculating -- 2% " message, don't use whole columns in array formulas, because it will involve millions of cells. Try to ringfence the range to only the rows with data. That can be done with named formulas if your data source table changes a lot.

Edit after comment: If you have an Office 365 version of Excel, you can use the Minifs function like this:

```
=MINIFS('Inventory Details'!C:C,'Inventory Details'!A:A,A2,**strong text**G:G,2)
```

Minifs is not an array formula and can be used on whole columns.

Comment: Thanks, your logic makes sense. I'm still not getting the result I am after.  I've attached revised images of the current result. I'll investigate named formulas as the inventory details sheet will populate via odata and be varying length

Comment: Current Formula
=(IF((A6='Inventory Details'!$A$2:$A$5)*('Inventory Details'!$D$2:$D$5<>'Inventory Details'!$E$2:$E$5),'Inventory Details'!$C$5:$C6,"a"))

Comment: Also, Office 365 introduces the [`MINIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/minifs-function-6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599) function.

Comment: All ranges must be the same size. You can't mix A2:A5 with C5:C6.  Also, the IF statement will return an array, so you must wrap something around it that processes the array, because you can't show an array in a cell. In my answer, the IF returns an array of dates and the MIN is wrapped around that to return the smallest of these dates.

Comment: I've also added another approach with Minifs.